# How to jumble an image?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

If the input is an image, my output should be a scrambled or jumbled image of the original image.  There isn't a need to divide the image into sub-blocks and scramble those regions individually.  You can scramble the entire image in one operation.  How can I achieve this in MATLAB?

Comment: In order to help, you're going to have to be more specific in what you mean by 'scrambled'.

Comment: Something like [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/35011)?

Comment: Also, these statements contradictory to me: 1. *no need to divide into regions and scrumble* 2. *Total image must be scrumbled.*.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar - Wow... that's basically what I did.  Cool!

Comment: @rayryeng I think they also have a bonus question that you should have same function for scrambling and unscrambling.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar - Ah... well with the method below that isn't possible.  That code golf website is cool.  Didn't even know it was part of SE.  Thanks for the link!

Comment: @rayryeng Beware... you may waste a lot of time on that :), for example, see [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/17005/produce-the-number-2014-without-any-numbers-in-your-source-code).

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar - hahahah! Wow! 2014 in multiple languages? I could be on that website forever!

Comment: This *is* a good question, SO is so wrong to use it as a test.

Answer (score 1):

If you what you mean by "scrambled" is by randomly re-arranging pixels in your image, you can create a random permutation vector that is as long as the total number of pixels in your image, reshape this so that it's the same size as the image, then use this to index into it.  Specifically, use [`randperm`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html) to help you do this.  As an example, let's use `cameraman.tif` that's part of MATLAB's system path.  Do something like this:

```
im = imread('cameraman.tif');
vec = randperm(numel(im));
vec = reshape(vec, size(im));
out = im(vec);
```

If you want to **undo** the scrambling, `vec` contains the column-major indices of where the pixels need to be remapped to in the original image.  Therefore, simply allocate a blank image, then use `vec` to index into this blank image and copy `out` back.  What this will do is that it will take the positions in the scrambled image, and copy them back in the locations that are indexed by `vec`.  This basically undoes the scrambling that we did before.  Therefore:

```
reconstruct = zeros(size(im), class(im));
reconstruct(vec) = out;
```

This is the original image:

[image]

This is what the scrambled image looks like:

[image]

Certainly looks noisy!... and scrambled... at least I think so.  By doing the reconstruction, this is what the image looks like:

[image]

---

The key to scrambling and unscrambling the image is to have that vector generated by `randperm`.  If you don't have this, then there's no way for you to reconstruct the original image.

Good luck!